# std::pair with or without standard layout: safe to reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, stl

If two classes `A` and `B` are of [standard layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) and `B` is defined as

```
class B {
  // any methods
  A a;
}
```

then it is safe to do

```
A a;
B* b = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&a);
```

---

If `A` now is replaced by `std::pair<T1, T2>`, will this work for every possible `T1, T2`, too? As far as I know, `std::pair<T1, T2>` is of standard layout if both `T1` and `T2` are of standard layout, but if they aren't, would this affect the possibility to safely `reinterpret_cast` in this case?

Comment: I think you are okay in this limited (`std::is_standard_layout`) situation.  Amiga OS used to do that sort of thing a lot.

Comment: There's some ambiguity here. There's nothing in the clause that defines a `std::pair` that explicitly states if `T1` and `T2` are a standard-layout-class then the resulting `std::pair` is a standard-layout class. It just describes the resulting class loosely, as a "pair" of `T1` and `T2`. I can see the argument that this loose implementation, combined with a more explicit definition of what a standard-layout class is, must mean that the resulting `std::pair` becomes a standard-layout pair. I would say that this is implementation-defined. Good question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: well, I've got this assumption from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687107/difference-between-stdpair-and-stdtuple-with-only-two-members):
`"Every std::pair<T, Y> is standard-layout if both T and Y are standard-layout."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `A` now is replaced by `std::pair<T1, T2>`, will this work for every possible `T1`, `T2` too?

No, it wouldn't even work in this specific case.

> would this affect the possibility to safely `reinterpret_cast` in this case?

Not at all. The cast is invalid in both cases.

You are violating the informal strict aliasing rule. More specifically, according to the standard, you are casting a pointer to an object (here `&a`, where `a` is the object) to `B*`. Any attempt to dereference that `B*` will be UB because you do not have an object `B`.

You might think that you have an object, but actually, according to the standard, you don't. From [[intro.object]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1.sentence-2):

> An *object* is created by a definition ([basic.def]), by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union ([class.union]), or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).

None of those cases apply, so you have UB if you try to use the "object" `b` which isn't one.

Now, you should consult with your implementation, because a lot of implementations provide a basic guarantee for constructs like yours IIRC.