# Is this downcast undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, static-cast

I am trying to extend `std::map`'s `std::pair` entries with some extra functionality and want to cast such pairs to a child class of pair. Note that this is the "wrong" direction of polymorphism, the child *is not* the parent. But since the memory layout should be identical as long as I am not introducing additional members in the child class, I am wondering if this is valid.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Concatenator : public std::pair<const std::string, std::string> {
public:
  operator std::string() const { return first + ", " + second; }
};

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::string> m{{"hello", "world"}};

  // Is this defined behaviour?
  Concatenator &c{*static_cast<Concatenator *>(&*m.begin())};
  std::cout << std::string{c} << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with overloading the `<<` operator so it produces the desired output? If this is too _implicit_ for you, you might also write a conversion function.

Comment: @Friedrich The usage of cout is just for this example, I like to have some object that has convenience function and uses an underlying pair object of a map. You are right however, that there are easy workarounds like writing a wrapper class that holds a reference to such a pair. However, when thinking about the problem, this came option came to my mind and now I just want to know it is a valid option.

Comment: Similar question (with a member not a base class, and with `reinterpret_cast` instead of your [definitely broken `static_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322985)): https://stackoverflow.com/q/49835673

Comment: @Artyer This question is not entirely similar because A is a member of B there and it can be padded or aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But since the memory layout should be identical as long as I am not introducing additional members in the child class...

No, that's wrong. That is undefined behavior.

Even without multiple inheritance, there is no guarantee that the memory layout is identical. Even if the memory layout *was* identical, then *it is still undefined behavior. Do not do this*.

Comment: OK and if I also throw in the additional restriction that I do not use multiple inheritance? Is it at least correct that the memory layout is identical?

Comment: no, unfortunately that's still undefined behavior no matter what.

Comment: OK I won't do this, thank you. Is it possible to give a counter example where the memory layout is not identical with packed or padding specifiers? Or is it just not guaranteed?

Comment: @phinz C++ only guarantees the order in specific cases, which are completely irrelevant, because the static_cast is undefined behavior regardless. It's also almost completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is well defined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Concatenator : public std::pair<const std::string, std::string> {
public:
    using base = std::pair<const std::string, std::string>;
    Concatenator(const base& o) : base(o) {}
    operator std::string() const { return first + ", " + second; }
};

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::string> m{{"hello", "world"}};

  Concatenator c = *m.begin();
  std::cout << std::string{c} << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this copies the pair.

Comment: It could make an internal reference. That would also be well defined